# Setting up Firebase for debug and release with a dev and release database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have two build types - `debug` and `release` - and two flavors, `dev` and `prod`.

The distinction is straightforward: `debug` is a debuggable binary, `release` is optimized, has debug code removed, and Proguard.

`dev` is meant to connect to a development Firebase project, `prod` is for the actual production database.

There are cases when I would like to use `debug` in the prod database, so I have all four possible combinations. The problem is that the project settings in Firebase require the SHA1 fingerprint of the signing key of the binary, and creating a debuggable application will always use the debug key.

I can't have the same key on two Firebase projects, so having the debug signing key on the dev Firebase project means I can't also have it on the prod one, so I cannot use the "prodDebug" setup (i.e. prod database with a debuggable binary).

What's the proper way to resolve this?

Comment: should this article be helpful in this case? https://medium.com/@Miqubel/multiple-build-types-in-firebase-on-android-6f6715f6dd83

Comment: @TRIENTRAN This is what I needed! If you want 25 reps, do you want to create an answer for this and summarize the points of the article (i.e. use a separate application ID)? if not, no problem, I can do that too.

Comment: That is very nice of you for the offer EboMike. I appreciate it but Francisco Durdin Garcia was quicker than me. Just wait for him to update his answer then. Is it possible if ask you that how can we find a job if we are fresh graduates with just a couple of months doing internship while employers looking for very experienced candidates?

Comment: @TRIENTRAN Google is hiring fresh grads, they also have well-paid internships. Of course, you'll need to make it through the interview, and that's not easy. I can only give you my standard advice - invest as much free time as you can just writing code, experimenting, looking at other people's code, etc... The more comfortable you are programming, the better your chances are in an interview.

Comment: Thank you so much indeed for the advice. I will try my best then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing element in the setup is outlined in the [Medium article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170118044523/https://medium.com/@Miqubel/multiple-build-types-in-firebase-on-android-6f6715f6dd83) (link via the Wayback Machine) posted in Fazan Cheng's comment.

Firebase does not allow the same SHA1 key *for the same application ID*. That means we can work around this problem by modifying the application ID in each flavor.

Specifically, this can be done with `applicationIdSuffix`, which add a string to the application ID. For example:

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
        versionNameSuffix "-dev"
        dimension 'env'
    }
    prod {
        versionNameSuffix "-prod"
        dimension 'env'
    }
}
```

If your application ID is `com.foo.myapplication`, the dev flavor will have the ID `com.foo.myapplication.dev`. You can now generate a separate Firebase project with this new ID and re-use the same SHA1 keys.

Comment: This Medium article link is not available anymore.

Comment: @LucianoBrum Thanks! Luckily it's still on the web archive. I'm going to update the link.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have two different Firebase Projects with two different `google.services.json` files. Both of them can have the same `SHA` keys associated to the project. To make it work you will need put each one of the files in the right folder of the project.

```
app/src/
    release/google-services.json
    debug/google-services.json
```

In this way, when you will compile your project, depending if it's a release version or a debug one, you will compile the project against one database or another. If you want to use custom flavors you can do the same, changing relase and debug for the name of your flavors:

```
app/src/
    flavor1/google-services.json
    flavor2/google-services.json
    flavor3/google-services.json
```

If you want more details about how this plugin work, give a look to: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54#issuecomment-165824720

Hope that it will help you!

Happy coding!

Comment: Your answer is missing the key part (I already had that double-json setup before) - you need a different application ID, otherwise they can't have the same SHA keys. Using `applicationIdSuffix` is the easiest way to do that. I'll accept your answer, but you should add that first.